# PGP keyserver and proxy firewall issues

Tags: networking, arch-linux, firewall, proxy, pgp

I am not sure this is a Linux question directly ... I use Arch Linux which uses package signing. This requires me to download a set of pgp keys with the `pacman-key` program. This works off the presumably more general `gpg` program. If I can get `gpg` to work, I am guessing I can get `pacman-key` working. The error I am getting suggests that the firewall I am behind is blocking the port (or something isn't set correctly in my proxy). I am behind a pretty restrictive university firewall and proxy, but the ports for things like ssh, ftp, and http are open and working, but it appears port 11371 is closed.

To debug my problem I tried going to http://pgp.mit.edu/, which works fine. When I try and download a key I get redirected to http://pgp.mit.edu:11371/ and then

```
HTTP Error Status: 403 Forbidden
Error Reason: Forbidden port
```

I think I am looking for a pgp keyserver that uses a port that might already be open in the firewall. Is there a different keyserver that I can use that works on a more "universal" port?

Comment: Like a proxy server? :-)

Comment: @HaukeLaging wouldn't the proxy server have to be outside the firewall?

Comment: Sure, that's the point. You use a server which you can reach through an allowed port and this server opens the connection to the blocked port for you.

Comment: @HaukeLaging thanks, I edited the question. I am trying to avoid that. I was hoping there might be a different keyserver that I could use, or a way to specify the port.

Comment: You may find keyservers using port 80 (too) with your preferred search engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, there are keyservers that listen on port 80.  One such keyserver is hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80.

Indeed, `pacman-key` uses `gpg` under the hood.

You might have tried specifying a keyserver by passing the `--keyserver` argument to `pacman-key`.  This didn't work for me.

You might have tried specifying a keyserver by creating or altering `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf`.  This didn't work for me.

Turns out that `pacman-key` is a bash shell script.  When it calls `gpg`, it specifies a config directory.  On my system this is `/etc/pacman.d/gnupg`.

Remove or comment out the existing `keyserver` and `keyserver-options` lines in `/etc/pacman.d/gnupg/gpg.conf`.  Add these lines:

```
keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80
keyserver-options verbose timeout=10
```

Notes:

- You don't have to use that specific keyserver, there's more than one out there which both contains keys relevant to Arch Linux and listens on port 80 or some other port your firewall doesn't block.
- Directly editing system-wide configuration files is acceptable on Arch Linux--they have a different philosophy about this sort of thing.

You should now be able to use the `pacman-key` command as expected.